# Elasticsearch returns hits instead of aggregation results

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to make composite aggregation on nested field `Rubrics` in Elasticsearch 8.7. Mapping of the index:

```json
{
  "item2": {
    "mappings": {
      "properties": {
        // omit non-related to question
        "Rubrics": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "Label": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              }
            },
            "Sentiment": {
              "type": "long"
            }
          }
        },
        // omit non-related to question
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My goal is to get buckets that looks like this:

```json
{ "buckets": [
   {
     "key": {
        "sentiment": 1,
        "rubric": "rubric_name_1"
     },
     "doc_count": 4
    },
    {
      "key": {
         "sentiment": 2,
         "pers": "rubric_name_1"
       },
       "doc_count": 3
    },
    // etc.. 
}
```

So, my query is:

```json
GET item2/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "sentiments_by_rubrics": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "Rubrics"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "my_buckets": {
          "composite": {
            "size": 10, 
            "sources": [
              {
                "sentiment": {
                  "terms": {
                    "field": "Rubrics.Label.keyword"
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "rubric": {
                  "terms": {
                    "field": "Rubrics.Sentiment"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Despite identical query works as intended on small index (~200 docs), when I'm trying to exec it on an index with ~70.000.000 docs, I got only search `"_hits"` and no `"aggregations"` section in response body (even though I set `"size: 0"` to not return any search results whatsoever) - like I just tried to make `index_name/_search` query without any request body at all.